# Create Azure subscription using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

We are unable to create azure subscription using below terraform code

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.56.0"
    }   
}
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  skip_provider_registration = "true"
  
}


data "azurerm_billing_enrollment_account_scope" "example" {
  billing_account_name    = "account name"
  enrollment_account_name = "account name"
}

resource "azurerm_subscription" "example" {
  subscription_name = "My Example EA Subscription2"
  billing_scope_id  = data.azurerm_billing_enrollment_account_scope.example.id
}


data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {
}

resource "azurerm_management_group" "example_parent" {
  display_name = "ParentGroup"

  subscription_ids = []
}

resource "azurerm_management_group" "example_child" {
  display_name               = "ChildGroup"
  parent_management_group_id = azurerm_management_group.example_parent.id

  subscription_ids = []
  # other subscription IDs can go here
}
```

Getting below error:

```
 Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
 azurerm_subscription.example: Creating...




╷
│ Error: creating new Subscription (Alias "6c92cfef-64f7-4ee4-b6b6-427501d2eab5"): subscriptions.SubscriptionsClient#AliasCreate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="InvalidSubCreationScope" Message="Not a valid subscription creation scope"
│ 
│   with azurerm_subscription.example,
│   on main.tf line 23, in resource "azurerm_subscription" "example":
│   23: resource "azurerm_subscription" "example" {
```

Not sure what is the issue in my case Billing Name and Billing Scope is same, in my above code it is "account name", or any other mistake i made?

My requirement is create subscription and assign it to management group